# File.open and YAML.load_file displaying different content for same file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

This is really strange. When I load a YML file from YAML.load_file and File.open display the same text but the numbers are different. Is this an encoding issue or something? I've never seen this before.

The file is bank.yml

```
production:
  account_number: 574827192
  routing_number: 048372651
```

*Side note: I changed the numbers in the below file so as to not reveal any actual private data.*

**UPDATE** => I realized the main problem is a result of the leading zero. You cannot have a leading zero in the YAML file or it turns in to an octal. Attempting to figure out how to structure the YAML file to contain leading zeroes.

```
> irb(main):027:0> YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/../../bank.yml")
> => {"production"=>{"account_number"=>574827192, "routing_number"=>847365987}}

> irb(main):028:0> File.open("#{Rails.root}/../../bank.yml").read
> => "production:\n  account_number: 574827192\n  routing_number: 048372651\n"
```

Comment: You didn't show us what is in the _actual_ text file - which one is right?

Comment: Ah @Uri Agassi, I updated to include that information

Comment: This is not valid `YAML`, you can check it here: http://yamltojson.com/

Comment: forgot a colon. its correct now. sorry i didn't directly copy since it's bank data

Comment: Do you recognize the numbers in the `YAML.load_file`? I could not reproduce it

Comment: I don't recognize them at all. There are completely random. I'm going to test it locally and on the server again and see what I can get.

Comment: Is there really a leading zero in the account numbers? If there is then they're not really numbers, they're strings that happen to consist of digit characters. If that's the case then you better quote them to make sure they're treated as strings.

Comment: There are not leading zeroes. I'll remove that for clarification sake. I did mention that the numbers were completely made up above.

Comment: Does the example you’ve given actually behave that way? I think you’ll need to find an example where the numbers actually change for anyone to work out what’s happening.

Comment: I just got a bit hint. I think it has to do with the routing number starting with a 0. It seems YAML files can't deal with zeroes. I'll change my example above.

Comment: If the number starts with a `0` and only contains characters <= 7 it will be parsed as octal.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. If someone wants to post the answer below, I'll award you the answer. I had to change the number to '012345' from 012345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the values in your YAML file in quotes, they will then be treated as strings and not drop the leading zero or parse it as octal:

```
production:
  account_number: '574827192'
  routing_number: '048372651'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you are doing `YAML.load_file`, it actually decodes `YAML` structure and gives you nice `hash`, which you can readily use.

However, when you do `File.open("file.yaml").read`, you are reading file in it's raw format, you have to further decode it, to use it as `hash` or some other data-structure.

Comment: Ok, but what do I need to do to ensure the numbers I input in the file are the actual values I want? Not sure if you saw my problem..

Comment: that should not had happened, What is in the original file, make sure there are no special chars in that.

Comment: Working fine in my local mac system, working just fine.